# What does the trailing "+" mean in file permission bits in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

I used `ls -a` to list a file and got the following information:

```
sqyang@intel4-88: ls -a 123 
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 root lsf 16845584 Nov 25 21:38 123*
```

The file permission part is `-rwxr-xr-x+`. What does the `+` mean at the end?

Answer (score 15):

> The "+" indicates that there is an ACL (Access Control List) entry
>   associated with the file.  I don't know about Linux, but ACLs are used
>   on Solaris too.  See the manual pages for "getfacl" and "setfacl".

[Source](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-11/msg00715.html)

Answer (score 2):

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_acl.htm

> For files that have a default ACL or an access ACL that contains more than the three required ACL entries, the ls(1) utility in the long form produced by ls -l displays a plus sign ( + after the permission string.